# how to remove the card that choose by player 1 from the switch statement using c++. (homework)

Tags: c++

This is the problem

- System shuffle and randomly assigned numbers 1-10 to the cards
- Player one pick a card
- System shuffle remaining cards and randomly assigned numbers 1-9 to the cards
- Player two pick a card

I am wondering how should I do this question by using if statement, switch statement, for and while loop? The following is my code and I use use if (number2 != number1). It work but it is not actually remove the card choose by player 1 right? Is there other way which is more make sense.

***Player 1:***

```
cout << name1 << ": Please enter a value to pick a card from 1 to 10.\n";
    cin >> number1;
    
    if (number1){
    
    int number1 = rand() % (9)+1;
    switch(number1)
    {
        case 0 : 
           }
```

***Player 2:***

```
if (number2 != number1){
    int number2 = rand() % (8)+1;
        switch(number2)
    {
        case 0 : 
        }
```

Thank you for you patient to read my question and please give me some suggestion if you have any interesting idea.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). C++ has this implemented right out of the box. See the example at the bottom of [this documentation page for `std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: If the cards are shuffled the first time, why shuffle again? it's not gonna make them more random. I would just shuffle once and start popping from the front/back/wherever. If the cards are shuffled, it doesn't matter what card the user picks so the input is irrelevant.

Comment: No part of your assignment says that `number1` must not equal `number2`. Seems to me that you should do what the question tells you instead of trying to do something that you think is equivalent. You need an array (of cards) you need to shuffle it, you need to remove a card from the array etc, etc. The code above does none of that.